# Wordpress slimmenu with JQuery

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm importing my HTML website to word press (creating a theme). Everything works, but I'm having an issue with a JQuery responsive menu plugin. The plugin can be found here

http://adnantopal.github.io/slimmenu/

For some reason, it just refuses to work (it works fine on my hosted website and locally on my machine).

I have tried calling the plugin via the functions.php file. Eventually I gave up and added the following lines in the head of my header.php file (i know this isn't good practice)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.slimmenu.js"></script>
```

To prove the scripts are called, I deleted everything in slimmenu.js and replaced the code with a single javascript alert (this worked fine).

Am i missing something obvious? Is there some sort of document onload that isn't fired in wordpress, or does wordpress prevent plugins from running?

Many thanks
P

Comment: Try replacing the first `$` in the script before the fuction with the word `jQuery` like so... `jQuery('#navigation').slimmenu(
{...`

Answer (score 0):

I think js/jquery.slimmenu.js, is not being included properly. You should use

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.slimmenu.js
```

while calling from header

Comment: This is good practice indeed, but he said that he tested that the scripts were being called with a javascript alert. So I don't believe this a problem.

Comment: view the source and click on this file. If you are able to see the file then its included.